# C forward-referencing structures - 1) must be with a pointer? 2) must be initialized?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, forward-reference

I'm trying to forward reference a (nested) structure, in C.

That means I have a structure and in it I'm referencing to another structure that is declared later.

If I declare the nested structure as a pointer, and initialize it with values, it works.

The following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct computer{
    double cost;
    int year;
    char cpu_type[16];
    struct cpu_speed *sp; //this is the question (1)
};

struct cpu_speed{
    int num;
    char type[16];
};

typedef struct computer SC;
typedef struct cpu_speed SS;

void DataR(SC *s);
void DataP(SC *s);

int main(){
   // this is question (2)
    SS speed = {4,"giga"};    
    SC model[2] = {
    { 0,1990, "intel", &speed},
    { 0,1990, "intel", &speed}
    };

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("computer no. %d \n", i+1);
        DataR(&model[i]);
    }
    printf("here's what you entered: \n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("computer no. %d \n", i+1);
        DataP(&model[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void DataR(SC *s){
    printf("the cost of your computer: ");
    scanf("%lf", &s->cost);
    printf("the year of your computer: ");
    scanf("%d", &s->year);
    printf("the type of cpu inside your computer: ");
    scanf("%s", s->cpu_type);
    printf("the speed of the cpu: ");
    scanf("%d %s", &(s->sp->num), s->sp->type);

}

void DataP(SC *s){

    printf("the cost: %.2lf\n",s->cost); 
    printf("the year: %d\n",s->year); 
    printf("the cpu type: %s\n",s->cpu_type); 
    printf("the cpu speed: %d %s\n",s->sp->num, s->sp->type);
}
```

If I declare the nested struct (i.e. `struct cpu_speed{...};`) before the parent(?) struct, I do not need to use a pointer, and I also don't need to initialize.

Meaning:

(1) I can use `struct cpu_speed speed;` instead of `struct cpu_speed *sp;`.
(2) I do not need to give initialized values to the structures variables.

My questions again - in forward referencing structure - (1) do you have to declare it with a pointer? and (2) do you have to initialize the values?

Comment: Just think: How would a recusive `struct` work? (while related, this is not about nesting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structures are only used by the compiler to align your memory. Thus, it needs to know the size of struct members.

```
struct foo {
    struct bar *pointer;
};
```

In this case, the `sizeof(pointer)` is unrelated to the `bar` struct and thus the compiler does not need to know anything more.

However, if you want to add the `bar` struct to the `foo` struct, it does need to know about its individual members.

```
struct bar {
    const char *string;
    uint64_t integer;
};

struct foo {
    struct bar sub;
};
```

You need to declare the `bar` struct before `foo` because the compiler needs to know what you're referring to. Otherwise, how would it know what to do with this (illegal) code:

```
struct bar {
    struct foo sub;
};

struct foo {
    struct bar sub;
};
```

Comment: ok, so basically you should preferably not use forward-referencing structures, and if you do - you have to use pointers, and initialize them. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with forward-referencing structures. For example, it's great when you use them to protect struct members from public facing APIs. But if you do, then you always have to use pointers and  `malloc` to create a new instance, yes.